# break statement not working to make loop stop

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have some values in database. 
I am fetching it and comparing it according to
my need but problem is its comparing it to the last value of the list.
If i get my values compared to the condition the loop should break and come out using the break in the loop if condition but its not working.
like the data is.

```
serial_number=1  
range_one_start=1.00    to  range_one_end=1.10  
range_two_start=20.00   to  range_two_end=20.40  
rate=1.00
------
serial_number=2  
range_one_start=1.11    to  range_one_end=1.20  
range_two_start=20.00   to  range_two_end=20.50  
rate=2.00  
------
serial_number=3  
range_one_start=1.21    to  range_one_end=1.30  
range_two_start=20.00   to  range_two_end=20.50  
rate=3.00
```

and so on i want to get data of serial_number 2 and so i will pass data
Range_one = 1.12 and Range_two = 20    so in ans i will get rate 2.00.
so the if condition will be like

```
if(1.12 >= 1.11 && 1.12 <= 1.20 && 20 >= 20.00 && 20 <= 20.50 )
    {
        Double rate_value = 2.00;

        break;
    }
```

below is my loop

```
 for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Double serial_number = Double.parseDouble(list.get(i).Serial_number_);
    Double range_one_start = Double.parseDouble(list.get(i).Range_one_start);
    Double range_one_end = Double.parseDouble(list.get(i).Range_one)end);
    Double range_two_start = Double.parseDouble(list.get(i).Range_two_start);
    Double range_two__end = Double.parseDouble(list.get(i).Range_two_end);
    Double rate = Double.parseDouble(list.get(i).Rate);
    if(Range_one >= range_one_start && Range_one <= range_one_end && Range_two >= range_two_start && Range_two <= range_two__end )
    {
        Double rate_value = rate;

        break; // this break statement is not working its not breaking the loop.
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use proper naming convention and clarify the question so that others can easily understand what do you need?

Comment: How do you know it is "not working"? Have you stepped through using a debugger? If you put logging statements right before and right after the `break`, do you see the first and not the second? BTW, you are declaring a local `rate_value` in that `if` block that never gets used for anything.

Comment: @KristopherJohnson yea i used degugger and rate_value is global variable just for the problem i have written in the the variable in if block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list_p_to_p_clr_buffalo.size(); i++) {
   Double serial_number =     Double.parseDouble(list_p_to_p_clr_buffalo.get(i).Serial_number_P_To_P_CLR_Buffalo);
   Double range_one_start = Double.parseDouble(list_p_to_p_clr_buffalo.get(i).fat_from_P_To_P_CLR_Buffalo);
   Double range_one_end = Double.parseDouble(list_p_to_p_clr_buffalo.get(i).fat_to_P_To_P_CLR_Buffalo);
   Double range_two_start = Double.parseDouble(list_p_to_p_clr_buffalo.get(i).CLR_from_P_To_P_CLR_Buffalo);
   Double range_two__end = Double.parseDouble(list_p_to_p_clr_buffalo.get(i).CLR_to_P_To_P_CLR_Buffalo);
   Double rate = Double.parseDouble(list_p_to_p_clr_buffalo.get(i).rate_P_To_P_CLR_Buffalo);
   Log.e("IF Condition == >", " " +(fatRate >= range_one_start && fatRate <= range_one_end && clrRate >= range_two_start && clrRate <= range_two__end ));

   try {
       if(fatRate >= range_one_start && fatRate <= range_one_end && clrRate >= range_two_start && clrRate <= range_two__end ) {
           Log.e("IF CONDITION DEBUG == >", "CONDITION OK");
           pToPClrRate = rate;
           Log.e("Rate***pToPClrRate* Buff** ==>",""+pToPClrRate);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // some code #3 (Write your code here to run in UI thread)
                    condition = true; 
                    refreshBtn.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });

            break; // this break statement is not working its not breaking the loop.
        }
        else{
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // some code #3 (Write your code here to run in UI thread)
                    condition = false; 
                    refreshBtn.setEnabled(false);
                 }
            });

            Log.e("IF CONDITION DEBUG == >", "CONDITION no else part");
        }


    } catch (Exception e) {
         // TODO: handle exception
         Log.e("Exception  == >", " "+ e);
    }

}
```

**Conclude:** Anyways check your condition.

Answer (score 0):

At first you should check your `if` condition you can use `Log` for debug.

```
Log.d("IF CONDITION DEBUG", "CONDITION OK");
```

Copy and paste this above code into your `if` condition. Then check your Log.

Comment: its coming only this this if condition when i enter serial_number=1   values if i enter serial_number=2 value it dont come in if condition

Answer (score 0):

Please verify your if condition :

```
if(Range_one >= range_one_start && Range_one <= range_one_end && Range_two >= range_two_start && Range_two <= range_two__end )
{}
```